# Push Button in second window does not work

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qpushbutton

I am new to PyQt5 and have a simple code where one window opens another. The second window contains `pushbutton`, which after pressing should print a message "push button clicked". The `pushbutton` works when the second window is called separately and not from the `mainwindow`. However, when the second window is called by the `mainwindow`, the `pushbutton` does nothing.

Code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 211, 111))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.print_method)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "This is another Window"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))

    def print_method(self):
        print("push button clicked")


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 190, 191, 91))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Another Window"))

    def show_new_window(self):

        self.Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui = Ui_Form()
        ui.setupUi(self.Form)
        self.Form.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `ui` object has no reference, so it gets deleted as soon as `show_new_window` returns. The result is that since the `print_method` function is a member of `Ui_Form`, it doesn't get called because that instance has been deleted.

A possibility could be to make the ui an attribute of the QWidget:

```py
    def show_new_window(self):
        self.Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Form.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.Form.ui.setupUi(self.Form)
        self.Form.show()
```

In any case, be aware that manually editing files generated by pyuic (or trying to mimic their behavior) is considered bad practice and highly discouraged, as it might lead to confusion and unexpected behavior. Read more about this topic on the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that if an answer has helped you to solve your problem, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tickmark on its left.